# It's not sunrise or sunset riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I hold the brightest of bright in a place with low light AND I am a place with low light that is not the night.

What am I?

Edit: The site wouldn't let me post the original version because it is not grammatically correct. I think it's better.

"Both brightest of bright and place with low light; what am I?"

Hint 1:

> It is one word with two meanings rather than one thing that meets both conditions.

Hint 2:

> The bright comes from above the dark goes deep underground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be

> **A hole** - OP clarified the answer is **A SHAFT**

I hold the brightest of bright in a place with low light

> A hole in the roof lets the light in - if you are in the dark place
>  - OP clarified shaft of light

I am a place with low light that is not the night.

> Looking down into or being in a hole - the deeper the darker
>  - OP clarified mineshaft

Rolled back Final guess

> **A Bar**

I hold the brightest of bright in a place with low light

> Modern flashlights are normally shaped as a bar holding the light at the end

I am a place with low light that is not the night.

> A bar (place to drink) is normally dimly lit (to an extent)

Comment: This is really close.  I would think about the characteristics of the light coming through the whole - like what is that called?

Comment: @personaelit, here's my final guess.  Thanks. Later.

Comment: The answer is shaft as in shaft of light and mineshaft.  @MacGyver88 gets the check as the answer("hole" is the closest.  Apologies to anybody who put effort into this as I think this is a good riddle, poorly executed. The parameters of the riddle got a wishy-washy when I tried to get flourish-y with the language which lead to too much room for interpetation, The best execution I can think of is "I am bright and come from above and I am dark and go deep underground. What am I?" Thanks everyone, and sorry for messing it up.

Comment: @personaelit, I don't think you messed it up.  The word just ended up having a few unexpected synonyms that "kind of" matched.

Comment: I appreciate that.  I could have done better.  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 5):

Second guess

> Limelight

Brightest of bright in a place with low light

> Limelight is both very bright literally as well as being used to describe someone enjoying attention in their field (in the limelight)

I am a place with low light that is not the night.

> in addition to being in a dark theater, limelights are also placed low on the stage

================
First incorrect guess

> A theater/movie screen?

Brightest of bright in a place with low light

> the movie screen is certainly the brightest thing in a low lit theater

I am a place with low light that is not the night.

> a theater lowers the light, and while it may happen at night, it's not because of the night

Comment: I think this works but was not my intent.  Brightest of bright is brightest of all brights.

Answer (score 1):

Is it the

> MOON

?

I hold the brightest of bright in a place with low light:

> The MOON is the brightest object in the night sky, which is certainly a place with low light.

I am a place with low light that is not the night:

> To MOON someone is to reveal one's bare bottom, which is idiomatically referred to as a place "where the sun don't shine", much like the night (but not the night).

Answer (score 0):

You may be

> the zenith

Both brightest of bright

> The zenith is the point where the sun (the "bright") gives the Earth the most direct sunlight and hence is at its brightest.

and place with low light

> Zenith is both the name of a [venue in Munich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenith_(building)) and a series of [indoor arenas in France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Z%C3%A9nith). Having no windows, those are places of [low](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Zenith_Nightclub_Munich_1.jpg) [light](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LCD_Soundsystem_au_Z%C3%A9nith_de_Paris_8.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the right answer, and in all honesty is mostly a guess, but here's my answer:

> A brain

Both brightest of bright:

> The brain can be the smartest (or brightest) thing that has ever been in existence. There is also one brain in the world that is smarter/brighter than any other brain in the world.

A place of low light that is not the night:

> It literally has low light because the skull will not let light in.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an

> Eclipse

Sun is brightest of the bright
And it has low light in an

> Eclipse

It is low light and is not the night

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Satellite

> A satellite is something in an orbit. The sun is technically a satellite as it orbits the black hole in the middle of the milky way

> Satellites are also the Satellites we know: The technical machines orbiting earth and providing us with information. They don't emit light and are pretty dark, because they just reflect light, but don't emit it

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is

> The Sun (or more generally, a star)

I hold the brightest of bright in a place with low light

> Stars can be said to be the "brightest of bright" but a star is also a [black body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body#:%7E:text=A%20black%20body%20or%20blackbody,can%20emit%20black%2Dbody%20radiation.), in that it is a perfect radiator and absorber of electromagnetic energy - hence a place of low light

I am a place with low light that is not the night.

> The suggestion that it is "not the night" makes me think that we might be referring to the Sun, in particular, which is responsible for giving us daylight.

Comment: I really like this, but it is not the answer I was going for.